# disable scrolling while scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I am writting a code , which animates scroll of 100% body.height. Everything works fine , but i am trying to disable the scrolling while the animation last to prevent further unwanted behavior.
i am using this code

```
function animate(x) {
    var start = new Date();
    var id = setInterval(function (e) {

        var timepassed = new Date() - start;
        var progress = timepassed / x.duration;
        if (progress > 1) {
            progress = 1;
        }
        var delta = x.delta(progress);
        x.step(delta);
        if (progress == 1) {
            clearInterval(id);

        }

    }, x.delay);


}

function fak(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

function move(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var wheel = e.wheelDelta;
    wheel = (wheel == 120) ? "-1" : "1";
    var body_height = document.body.offsetHeight;
    var scrollIt = body_height * wheel;
    var page = window.pageYOffset;
    animate({
        delay: 10,
        duration: 700,
        delta: function (p) {
            return p;
        },
        step: function (delta) {
            window.scrollTo(0, page + (delta * scrollIt));
        }
    });
    return false;
}
document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", move, false);
document.body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", move, false);
```

I tried to assign function fak , on mousewheel , mousescroll in interval and then restoring original assigment to them at the end using

```
function animate(x) {
    var start = new Date();
    var id = setInterval(function (e) {
    document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", fak, false);
    document.body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", fak, false);
        var timepassed = new Date() - start;
        var progress = timepassed / x.duration;
        if (progress > 1) {
            progress = 1;
        }
        var delta = x.delta(progress);
        x.step(delta);
        if (progress == 1) {
            clearInterval(id);
  document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", move, false);
  document.body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", move, false);

        }

    }, x.delay);


}
```

But didnt work either. Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/o2pvo2t8/ Did i overlook something?

Comment: I cant stretch that often enough.. Use debug output. one line of code `console.log(wheel);` and you know the answer. `wheel` is undefined.

Comment: wheel is not undefined , and scrolling works fine , what i am trying to do is to disable scrolling while animation is in progress.

Comment: if you insert `console.log(wheel);` after `var wheel = e.wheelDelta;`, you can see, that wheel is undefined... http://jsfiddle.net/o2pvo2t8/1/

Comment: You must be using firefox wich does not support e.wheelDelta but  e.detail. I forgot to add support for firefox. I should have said it . im sorry.

Comment: i thought about this, but im at work so i had no time to google that. so problem persists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i changed a bit on your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/o2pvo2t8/2/

just set a flag "running" while scrolling (at start of animate() ), and clear it at the end.
and execute mov only when no scrolling appears.

hope it helps.

```
var running;

function animate(x) {
    running = 1;
    var start = new Date();
    var id = setInterval(function (e) {

        var timepassed = new Date() - start;
        var progress = timepassed / x.duration;
        if (progress > 1) {
            progress = 1;
        }
        var delta = x.delta(progress);
        x.step(delta);
        if (progress == 1) {
            clearInterval(id);
            running = 0;
        }

    }, x.delay);


}

function fak(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

function move(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (running==1) return;
    var wheel = e.wheelDelta;
    console.log(wheel);
    wheel = (wheel == 120) ? "-1" : "1";
    var body_height = document.body.offsetHeight;
    var scrollIt = body_height * wheel;
    var page = window.pageYOffset;
    animate({
        delay: 10,
        duration: 700,
        delta: function (p) {
            return p;
        },
        step: function (delta) {
            window.scrollTo(0, page + (delta * scrollIt));
        }
    });
    return false;
}
document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", move, false);
document.body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", move, false);
```

Comment: Thanks , cant believe again , the solution was so simple :/